# Balance multicols with leading instead of paragraph spacing

Tags: multicol, line-spacing, parskip

I have a book that is utilizing the `multicols` package, but I'm having one issue. Sometimes I end up with radically different paragraph spacing on a page or spread. Here's an example:

[image]

I'm able to overcome this by using `\spacing` around a few of the paragraphs, but this becomes overwhelming given that this is an 800+ page book. Is there any option or simpler way of achieving this?

Here's an example of what I'm wanting it to look like.

[image]

Comment: you can make baseline a stretchy space (but I'm not sure I would recommend that) `\setlength\baselineskip{15pt plus 2pt}` for example

Comment: if you provided a test document that produced the first image you would be more likely to get answers

Answer (score 1):

I fear without additional data about your setting there is not much advice that can be given. But in any case I doubt that you can have an algorithmic solution.

The statement I prefer output B over output A doesn't really doesn't give much to go on algorithmically. From the pictures I guess ou prefer to run both columns short by an identical amount in case one (or both) of them show some excessive stretch. But this is not something TeX can easily handle because cutting a column earlier might result in worse outcome in later columns so an algorithm would need to do a lot of trial typesetting.

Note that this has nothing to do with multicol: this would be exactly the same in normal twocolumn mode.

For a semi-manual solution I suggest to use `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` which should give you your wanted result on pages you think need fixing with much less effort than manual fiddling with spacing in several places.